# Animating navigation with scroll and click jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, skrollr

I'm attempting to animate a navigation. At first the navigation does not show up. You must scroll down the viewport however many pixels for it to fadeIn. Then when you click on a link in the nav, I am attempting to animate the navigation, by making it move from the middle of the page to the top of the page.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/g8urqu8b/

& here is my actual webpage I am working on: http://www.unf.edu/~n00804716/my-site/

On my real site, when a link in the nav is clicked there is also a div that I fadeOut while I fadeIn a new one that was not previously displayed. This is why it is necessary for the window to scrollTop when a nav link is clicked; so the user is able to scroll down the newly presented div from the top of the document.

So essentially, I believe I'm asking if there is there a way to kill this scroll function with a separate click function:

```
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() < 500) {
            $("ul.click").fadeOut(400);
        } else {
            $("ul.click").fadeIn(400);
        }
      });
```

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g8urqu8b/1/?

Comment: @TahirAhmed Yes, thank you! If you could, do you think you could explain how it works? To my basic understanding, it's because you're not binding by using .on  and .off functions. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if I understood this correctly, **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/g8urqu8b/1/)** is the kind of result you are expecting.

***JavaScript:***

```
$("div").hide();
function onScroll() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 150) {
        $("div").fadeOut(400);
    } else {
        $("div").fadeIn(400);
    }
}
$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "top": "50px"
    }, 500)
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    $(window).off('scroll', onScroll);
});
```

The idea is to be able to use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** (and **[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**) method of jQuery to listen (or to not listen) to scroll events.

The second parameter to both `.on()` and `.off()` methods is the callback, in our case, it is a function by the name **`onScroll`**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood...

You want to clear the scroll function of the window when you do click on the ul element??

Comment: Yes, so that when I click on the ul element and the window returns to the top, the ul does not fadeOut –